# Applescript folder action for "Messages" text, tweak needed

Tags: applescript, message, imessage

I have a folder action that sends me a text message via Messages when a new file is added to the folder and it works (sort of). Here it is:

```
on adding folder items to this_folder after receiving added_items
    set added_Items_List to {}
    set dateString to (current date) as string
    set theBody to "New items have been added to " & name of (info for this_folder) & ": "

    tell application "Messages"
        set theBuddy to buddy "E:scottl44@this.net" of service "E:scott@that.com"
        send theBody & dateString to theBuddy
    end tell

end adding folder items to
```

The problem is, if 200 files are added, it sends 200 texts.

I'd like it to just send me a message upon the first file added, and then ignore any more for a given interval, like 30 minutes. Is this possible?

Also, I'd like it to get the folder path, at least one folder up from where it is.

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

Try using a temporary file. You can get the full path of the folder with `POSIX path of this_folder`:

```
on adding folder items to this_folder after receiving added_items
    do shell script "f=${TMPDIR}messagesfolderaction;[[ ! -e $f || $(stat -f%m $f) -le $(date +%s)-1800 ]]&&touch $f||echo a"
    if result is not "" then return
    set body to "New items have been added to " & POSIX path of this_folder & (current date) as text
    tell application "Messages"
        send body to buddy "E:scottl44@this.net" of service "E:scott@that.com"
    end tell
end adding folder items to
```

Comment: Hmm.. is there anything I need to do besides correct the domain names in the addresses? Nothing seems to happen when I enable this. Thanks!

Comment: Really nice! I've added one file and got the message, then several files and no message. Great! Now I'm waiting to add more after the 30 min.

Just one question: If I want to send to more than one person, then do I only have to duplicate the "send body to buddy.." line with the address changed appropriately?

Comment: So now after 30 min., I add files, but don't get a message. Any ideas? This is great, thanks so much for your help.

Comment: @scottl31 I really should test these scripts better. There was another error but try it again now.

Comment: As I was testing it, I changed the interval to 3 min. so it would be easier. If I added another file or more before the 3 min. was up, it would send another message when the 3 min was up. This is amazing, thanks!

Comment: That last comment was for the previous one. I'm trying the new one now!

Comment: Nice! Seems to work great! Just few fine tuning questions, - If I want to send to more than one person, then do I only have to duplicate the "send body to buddy.." line with the address changed appropriately? - Also, I can't figure out what to enter in order to separate the date from the folder path with maybe a period and a return, or just a semicolon.

Comment: Yeah, just duplicating the send line should work. You can use `& "." & linefeed &` to add a period and a linefeed.